# react-boilerplate add custom environment variable

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate, react-scripts

i want to add custom environment variables when using react-boilerplate. 
In my DEV environment i will point the API to my localhost backend, but in PROD environment i will point it to the PROD backend.
I have tried using [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) and [react-scripts](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) but still won't work.
for the dotenv-webpack i have add the plugins code below dllPlugin.

```
dllPlugin: {
...
},

plugins: [
new Dotenv({
  path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default) 
  systemvars: true,
  safe: true // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe) 
})
]
...
```

anyone have succeed applying this feature ? please throw some enlightment..

Answer (score -2):

I have successfully implement the dotenv-webpack to the react-boilerplate. Before I misplaced the config at /config.js. Now i put in webpack/webpack.base.babel.js.